# phenolsulphonic acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, electrochemistry, organosulfur-compounds

Phenolsulfonic Acid( PSA) is produced after sulphonation of Phenol at around 100 degrees. They use this product in tinplating.
Once a stable PSA is formed after sufficient reaction , unreacted impurities are Phenol 2% max , Sulphate  3% max. PSA is to be 65%  minimum and rest is water.
After few days , Sulphate is increasing to 3.5 to 4.5% or even more, while others remain constant.
The question is:
Why sulphate concentration is increasing from the initial value of 3% on day 1 to 4% on day 5/6. I dont have a chemistry background so any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: a crystalline PSA is formed after mixing phenol and sulphuric acid at 100 degrees, take the crystalline product and cool it down to about 50 degrees and add water.  we were getting final PSA with unreacted impurities of Phenol 2% max, Sulphate 3% max. PSA is to be 65% minimum and rest is water. After 2-3 days , Sulphate is increasing to 3.5 to 4.5% or even more, phenol remain constant. small company only makes PSA for the last 15 years and never encountered this issue. The question is: Why sulphate concentration can elevate above 3% after 2 days. Any help/suggestions is appreciated. Thanks